# how to filter a divider based on checkboxes checked using multiple css classes

Tags: jquery, html, css

Let's say that I have two checkboxes

One checkbox has the id `myCheckboxOne` and the other has the id `myCheckboxTwo`. Both checkboxes have the class `checkbox`.

I then have a divider with the class `myCheckboxOne-div myCheckboxTwo-div`.

I run an `$.each` loop using jQuery on each `.checkbox` class.

If the first checkbox is checked, it gets the ID value, which is `myCheckboxOne`, it shows the divider with the class `myCheckboxOne-div` or else it hides it.

However, if the second checkbox is not checked, it gets the ID value, which is `myCheckboxTwo`, it hides the divider with the class `myCheckboxTwo-div`, which means that it overrides the first decision.

I want to find a way to keep the divider shown if at least one checkbox is checked that matches the class name.

```js
   $( document ).ready(function() {
  
  
$(document).on('click', '.check', chkBtns);
  
function chkBtns() {
  
  var idboxes;
  var i = 0;
  
$( ".check" ).each(function( index ) {

idboxes = "." + $(this).attr("id") + "-div";// raul - dot is the class 
  
if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
  //alert('test');
  $("label[for="+$(this).attr("id")+"]").css("background-color", "#fdb813");
  $("label[for="+$(this).attr("id")+"]").css("color", "#000");
  
        i++;
     
          $(idboxes).show();
    
  
 // alert(idboxes);
 }
 else
  {

  $("label[for="+$(this).attr("id")+"]").removeAttr('style');
      
            //if at least non "class" was found
  
       $(idboxes).hide();
     
            
  }
  


});
  
 /* if no boxes are check, reset the divs*/
  if (i == 0) {
    $(".all").show();
  }
 

  
  
} // function

  
});
```

```css
.lbl-all {
  background-color: #bbb;
  padding: 7px;
  border-radius: 5%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>

  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.js" integrity="sha256-WpOohJOqMqqyKL9FccASB9O0KwACQJpFTUBLTYOVvVU=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <input type="checkbox" id="firstcheckbox" name="check" class="firstcheckbox check"> 
  <label for="firstcheckbox" class="lbl-firstcheckbox lbl-all">My First Checkbox</label>
  
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="secondcheckbox" name="check"  class="secondcheckbox check"> 
  <label for="secondcheckbox" class="lbl-secondcheckbox lbl-all">My Second Checkbox</label>
  
  
  <input type="checkbox" id="aascheckbox" name="check"  class="aascheckbox check"> 
  <label for="aascheckbox" class="lbl-aascheckbox lbl-all">AAS</label>
</body>
</html>



<div class="firstcheckbox-div all" style="width: 300px;">First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First First 
</div>

<br /><br />

<div class="secondcheckbox-div aascheckbox-div all" style="width: 300px;">Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second Second 
</div>
```

Here is my working codepen: https://codepen.io/raulgonzalez77/pen/dybxKoy

Comment: You're missing a `});` after the else statement. You'll also need to remove the bracket `)` after the else in your codepen

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE:

I'm relying on a bit sloppy code, but for now what works is to check if the current element has the class of another class

See my Codepen for full version: https://codepen.io/raulgonzalez77/pen/dybxKoy

```js
///////////////dev code////////////
if ($(".check-aas").is(':checked')) {
    if ($(idboxes).hasClass('aascheckbox-div')) {
            //do some thing 
      i++;
            $(idboxes).show();
            //alert(idboxes);//dev alert
    }
}
```

Comment: if you add code snippet then I think it would be better you add whole code...